# jquery replace multiple span by one span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, I have a string text like this

```
<span> You</span> <span>have</span> <span>20</span> <span>minutes</span><span> to</span><span> <span>complete</span><span> each</span><span> test</span>
```

All words are contained in span tags.
But now I need to replace a multiple string by one string catch by span. For example if my string is :

```
You have
```

I need to replace

```
<span> You</span> <span>have</span>
```

with

```
<span>You have</span>
```

in the text.

Very important, my string to be replaced is dynamic (can be "to complete", or "each test"), so my final text will be

```
<span> You have</span><span>20</span> <span>minutes</span><span> to</span><span> complete</span><span> each</span><span> test</span>.
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please be careful when formatting the code in your question. This made very little sense before I edited it.

Comment: Are you randomly downvoting? Or do you have any reasons to automatically downvote?

Comment: @SrAxi do you mean me? If so, no. I haven't downvoted anything. Although neither of the answers will create the output the OP specifies, so the downvotes could be merited.

Comment: Please format the question properly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not you. The owner of the OP. As soon as the answers were posted they received a downvote. I think that at least a comment on why they have been downvoted should be provided.

Comment: sorry, I corrected

Comment: On what basis `<span> You</span> <span>have<span>` only get converted to `<span>You have<span>` but not `<span> complete</span><span> each</span><span> test</span>`? This question is not making any sense. You do have to re-frame the question.

Comment: please check the edit of mine your problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

You can just select the `span` using jQuery and then use its `text` and remove all them and append the text to a new span.

```
var txt = $('span').text(); // get the text
$('span').remove(); // remove them
$('body').append('<span>' + text + '</span>'); // append a new one with the gotten text
```

If you want only first n spans, you could do

```
var txt = $('span:lt(n-1)').text(); // of course don't type n-1 as it is. Calculate!
```

Comment: After decrypting the question, I think this should be the solution

Comment: I don't think it would be, as it replaces the text of all spans. It does not join the `You` and `have` spans - which is what the output should be. DV isn't mine FYI

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Right! Didn't see that. I never said you downvoted, I ment the OP owner. I just don't like 'insta' downvoted without any reasoning.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan haha DV once used to irk me, but nowadays it's business asusual.:)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work just fine

```
var pspan=null;
var arr=[];
$( "span" ).each(function( index ) {
  if(index==0) pspan=$(this);   
  arr.push($.trim($(this).text()));
});
pspan.text(arr.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this:

```
var html = '<span> You have</span><span>20</span> <span>minutes</span><span> to</span><span> complete</span><span> each</span><span> test</span>.';
var newHtml = "";
$(html).find("span").each(function (index, value) {
    newHtml += value;
});
newHtml = "<span>" + newHtml + "</span>";
```

That's it ;-)